Fantasy book about a woman hired to tend to a challenged man
I'm trying to find a book (maybe from the 70's or 80's) set in modern times, in which a woman is hired to take care of a challenged man presumably created by her warlock employer. Then she starts living a parallel life in a fantasy world in her dreams.
The book is pretty dark and sexually explicit, so is not oriented towards young audiences.

Hi Marcos and welcome to the SFFSE :-) Just to be clear, is the woman hired by a warlock who she knows is a warlock? And she is hired to look after a man who may or may not be a victim of the warlock? And where does the fantasy world come in? What causes he to start fantasising? The man she is looking after?

She has next to no information about the job except taking care of a mentally challenged man. The employer doesn’t hide his “eccentricities” and she starts dreaming the first night in the house. I think
